# Manking sense of an entropy equal $k_B\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

In problems of impurities coupled with electrons in a conduction band, like the [Kondo model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kondo_model), is common to represent the entropy contributed by the impurity, in terms of bits, i.e. in units of $k_B\ln(2)$. In this unit, the entropy is understood as a number of two-level degrees of freedom that are thermally available at some temperature. When we have a kondo model, for example, the entropy is equal $1$ until the [Kondo effect](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kondo_effect) start to show up, and for temperatures much more low than the Kondo temperature the entropy is zero.

In this paper: [cond-mat/0701105v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0701105v1), we have what is called two channel Kondo model entropy in the page $16$ at the figure $6$. The entropy for small temperatures is equal $\frac{1}{2}$. I do not have an physical interpretation of that very clear in my head.

I have worked on in similar models (with two levels in the impurity), and sometimes this entropy $\frac{1}{2}$ shows up. What I know is that:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\ln(2) = - \frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2}) = - P_i \ln(P_i)
$$

that is a term of the [Gibbs entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(statistical_thermodynamics)#Gibbs_entropy_formula). The only thing that I know for sure is that the impurity and conduction band have some correlation, in other words:

$$
P_{AB} \neq P_A+P_B
$$

where, $A$ is some microstate of the impurity and $B$ of the conduction band. $P_{AB}$ is the probability of some microstate of the system $A+B$.

Question: There is some deep interpretation of that result?